# Can I drop a file into codenameone desktop apps?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way for codenameone Desktop Build apps to handle dropping a file into it? Or any "File Browser" component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [native interface](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) in the Java SE implementation and add an AWT drop listener to the main window.